# MsysGit gets differend look&feel depending on, how it is called

Tags: command-line, git, msysgit, msys

When I start msysgit (`C:\msysgit\msysgit\msys.bat`) from its directory, it has an other visual settings, as when I start it over a shortcut in the Quick Launch.

[image]

[image]

Why? How can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the Quick Launch shortcut and select Properties. You should be able to adjust visual styles like Font, Layout, Colors from there.

If you directly run msys.bat it will use whatever defaults your cmd is set to.

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to set every single property or is it possible to use the "defaults my cmd is set to", when the msysGit is started from Quick Launch?

Comment: Yes, open regedit, go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Open the "Console" key, there you see all the general settings and defaults. If you open the msysgit subkey you'll see all values that apply only to msysgit. Remove the values to revert to system standard. Be sure to backup before you change anything in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Another way to quick launch msysGit with the default command line settings is to add the msysGit folder to the `path` environment variable. The one can start it from Windows Start menu (just typing `msys` in).